# Kusto - how to ingest from query using management (.show) function

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to have a table that stores only daily tables sizes.

But it won't work this way:

```
.set-or-replace async tables_daily_storage <| 
(
.show cluster extents 
| where MinCreatedOn  >= startofday(now())
| project DatabaseName,TableName,OriginalSize,D=bin(MinCreatedOn,1d) 
| summarize total_size=sum(OriginalSize) by DatabaseName, TableName
)
```

Because I used .show function which is a management function.

Is there anything to get around this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply remove the brackets
[doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query)

```
.set-or-replace async tables_daily_storage <| 
.show cluster extents 
| where MinCreatedOn  >= startofday(now())
| project DatabaseName,TableName,OriginalSize,D=bin(MinCreatedOn,1d) 
| summarize total_size=sum(OriginalSize) by DatabaseName, TableName
```